# Primitive notions for positiv types

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I am currently trying to understand how to formalize homotopy type theory in Church-style as proposed in the second appendix of the HoTT book.

How am I supposed to interpret the constructors of positive types as the $\sum$- type, the coproduct type, the natural numbers or the identity type?

Is $\mathrm{inl}$ in the second appendix a meta-theoretic notion? If so, would this mean that $\mathrm{inl}$ isn't a term of our formal theory and we cannot construct a function $\lambda (a:A).\mathrm{inl}(a):A\to A+B$? I'm just wondering as I always pictured the constructors of the coproduct as injections.

Comment: inl is indeed a term of the formal theory, as are the constructors of the other positive types.

Comment: @MikeShulman thanks for the answer. If it is a term of the formal theory it should be typed, so I guess its type is $A\to A+B$. Does this mean that the conclusion of the $+-\mathrm{Intro_1}$ could then be changed from $\Gamma\vdash \mathrm{inl}(a):A+B$ to $\Gamma\vdash\mathrm{inl}:A\rightarrow A+B$?

Comment: Yes, you can write the rule either as "if $\Gamma\vdash a:A$ then $\Gamma \vdash \mathrm{inl}(a):A+B$" or "$\Gamma\vdash \mathrm{inl}:A\to A+B$".  The former is preferred for technical reasons ("admissibility of substitution"), but semantically both mean the same thing.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thanks, now it is clear. Can you recommend any literature that contains proofs of the admissibility of the structural rules like for example substitution? Furthermore I would be interested in a proof of the normalization result...

Comment: Why don't you ask that as another question (note that it's not about homotopy type theory, just type theory) -- other people than I would be more qualified to answer.